# Bootstrap custom fonts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I've been looking at the bootstrap custom fonts issues on here to find a solution for mine but it is still not working so I apologize for the repetition. Trying to get 'Museo Slab' into my page and its not working. Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

---

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo-slab';
    src: url('fonts/Museo500-Regular.otf');
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: 'museo-slab',arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 23px;
```

Comment: @RobertLevy it is not rendering on my page.

Comment: What, you're only loading one font-file variant? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: @Paulie_D Im using it because Im told IE8 supports it. I can add more though I just want to see my fonts working

Comment: As you can see from the snippet I provided it looks like your code will not work for IE8.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok so adding more font formats is what I need to do? As of right now the museo slab isnt rendering at all. Thats all im trying to do. Im just making a landing page locally using bootstrap and chrome and just want to see page layout with the correct font.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no solution for IE8 and the questioner found an answer but did not post it and apparently has abandoned this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the image for browser compatible font extensions. You have to use different extensions for different browsers. 
Here is the simple guide for it:   http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/